# django Test discovery Issues

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

i run `./manage.py test` and i got this err

```
...

test_create_default_action_with_deadline (masoon.anomalies.tests.anomaly.AnomalyCreateDefaultAction) ... ok
masoon.actions.admin (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
masoon.actions.models (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
masoon.anomalies.models (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
...
======================================================================
ERROR: masoon.actions.admin (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: masoon.actions.admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vahid/project/py/django/masoon/actions/admin/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .actions import ActionsAdmin
  File "/home/vahid/project/py/django/masoon/actions/admin/actions.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ActionsAdmin(AbstractBaseAdmin):
  File "/home/vahid/project/py/django/masoon/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/decorators.py", line 100, in _model_admin_wrapper
    admin_site.register(models, admin_class=admin_class)
  File "/home/vahid/project/py/django/masoon/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 126, in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered(msg)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Action is already registered with 'actions.ActionsAdmin'.
```

**its not related to register admin. its relayed to discovery test file. unittest discover my admin fils as test and try to run it**

filetree:

```
...
├── actions
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── action_report.py
│   │   ├── actions.py
│   │   ├── answer.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   |   ├── ...
│   ├── tests
│   |   ├── actions.py
│   |   ├── answers.py
...
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── action.py
│   │   ├── action_report.py
│   │   ├── answer.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
├── infrastructure
│   ├── asgi.py
│   │       ...
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├──settings
...
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── files.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logging.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
...
├── manage.py
...
```

but when i run `./manage.py test modulname.tests`
all test pass and django dont discover my models as test.

my setting modules `__init__` like this :

```
...

from .apps import *
from .middlewares import *
from .drf import *

...
```

`__init__` of test or models or etc module somthing like this

```
from .anomaly import AnomalyCreateDefaultAction, AnomalyAPITest
```

Why is it that unittest  discover my admins classes and my model classes

as a test to run it

Comment: You can not register a model more than once in admin. Check other files to make sure it has not been registered in other places.

Comment: @moeinBabapour its not related to register admin. its relayed to discovery test file. unittest discover my admin fils as test and try to run it.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Although Django's base `TestClass` discovers the tests as if they're in the pattern of `test_*.py` and I'm not sure why it discovers wrongly, you can use `--pattern` option to specify the pattern for discovery.

Comment: also i try to use pattern but djano discover my models as test @Sadra